# How to deactivate mbox?

Tags: debian, dovecot, imap

I just finished to install the horde framework (git version) on my server (debian7 + dovecot + postfix + apache2).

And I would like to know if it is possible to deactivate the "mail" program's "maildir to mailbox" conversion. Everytime I read my mail using "mail" throught a ssh session, it moves my mail from /var/mail/USERNAME to my mbox.

Any reponse or hint would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Don't use mail to read your mail?  Instead use mutt or something else?

Comment: It's a workaround yes, but mail displays a notifcation on my ssh session everytime I connect (something like "you've got new mail"). And call me a maniac yes, but I'm not satisfied with that solution, it feels dirty, like skirting the probleme instead of resolving it.

But thank you for your response anyway

Answer (score 0):

Ok so my whole installation was a mess.
postconf was still configured to write mail to /var/mail/USERNAME
. Dovecot "sent" and "draft" mails were saved to /home/USERNAME/mail/ using mbox

so I reconfigured all that and decided to use mailDir
To do so, I reconfigured postfix by doing

```
postconf -e "home_mailbox = Maildir/"
postconf -e "mailbox_command ="
```

and changed dovecot mail_location variable (in dovecot.conf)

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
```

And, everything seems fine, "mail" do not bother me with useless notices and conversion anymore. It SEEMS like he only look for mail in /var/mail/USERNAME. I might be wrong, I'm no mail expert.

Hopefully someday it might help someone.